# If x, y, and z are random numbers from 0 to 1, what is the probability that x+y+z<1?

Tags: probability, random

If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are random numbers from $0$ to $1$, what is the probability that $x+y+z<1$?

I know that the answer is $\frac{1}{6}$ but I am not sure how to get there. If this problem had two variables, I could graph $x+y<1$ and look at the area to find the answer.

Comment: Can you see that $x+y+z < 1$ with $0 < x,y,z < 1$ is the region enclosed by the simplex $x+y+z=1$ and the crosssections of the simplex and the $xy, yz, xz$ planes?

Comment: "*If this problem had two variables, I could graph $x+y<1$ and look at the area to find the answer.*"  Good, that is a correct way to think about it from a geometric standpoint.  If you wish to continue thinking in terms of geometry, just start thinking in three dimensions instead.  If you are unable to visualize past this point, then consider using integral calculus to describe it as a triple integral with appropriately selected bounds to represent your specific region.

Comment: You should specify that the numbers have a uniform probability for this problem to be well defined.

Answer (score 1):

The following must be satisfied:

$$z \lt1-x-y$$

$$y \lt 1-x$$

$$x \lt 1$$

Thus, we have the integral

$$P(x+y+z \lt 1) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-y} 1  dz dy dx = \frac{1}{6}$$

Not that, for example, $y$ doesn't actually *have* to be less than $1-x$ but we can suppose it is just because $x,y,z$ ~ $unif(0,1)$. It could have equivalently been

$$x \lt 1-y-z$$

$$z \lt 1-y$$

$$y \lt 1$$

You can interchange these variables as you'd like, as long as you change the order in which you integrate accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of variety:

A geometric answer can be obtained by recognizing that in the unit cube (which has volume $1$), the desired subset is that pyramid whose apex is one of the vertices, and whose base is spanned by the three adjacent vertices.

Since the cube can be decomposed into such four such pyramids (the one described above, plus three more, each with an apex at one of the vertices at distance $\sqrt{2}$ from the first apex) plus a central tetrahedron with twice the volume, each pyramid must have volume $\frac16$.  That's the desired probability.

Not necessarily the way you want to go about figuring this out, but it's a sanity check.  (In a manner of speaking.)